# How to pass STDIN to wall in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, stdin

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/wall.1.html

The OS X `man` page seems to be almost identical to the Linux one, at least at the beginning, wherein it mentions where the command takes input from. It states STDIN by default. However it doesn't mention needing `superuser` for reading from file, unlike the Linux `man`.

Consequently, reading from a file seems to be default behaviour, and `wall` on OS X simply looks for a file regardless of whether I've given given it a filename or an actual message, failing in the latter case.

As a stopgap I've been using a heredoc to send messages through `wall`

How do I make wall read from STDIN like it mentions in the manual?

Running OS X 10.10.3

EDIT: I'm not writing a script, I'm just typing in `wall hello world` into a `zsh` shell in Terminal on OS X. Same results with `bash` and `sh`.

EDIT 2: The response from the shell is actually
`usage: wall [-g group] [file]`
or
`no such file or directory` (if I surround the message with quotes)

Comment: Would you please add t the relevant parts of the script you are currently using so we can see the use case?

Comment: I'm not writing a script. My use case is literally typing `wall hello world` into a zsh shell in Terminal on OS X.

Comment: OSX `wall` reads from stdin just fine. When you run `wall hello world`, you're specifying the message on the _command line_, not stdin.

Comment: You're right, `echo hello world | wall` works. How does the Linux wall work then? It seems to automatically decide on taking the subsequent input as STDIN or a filename if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you saw that Linux uses a different version of `wall` than OS X, right?  One is GNU and the other is BSD and they have different usages.